# Access bottle post parameters

Tags: python, node.js, windows, bottle

I am posting two post parameters with node js to bottle service using axios library

```
var axios = require('axios')

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/filter-tags', {
   xml: 'Fred',
   tags: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

My bottle service is

```
from bottle import route, run, request
from pprint import pprint

@route('/filter-tags', method='POST')
def filterTags():
    xml1 = request.POST.xml
    xml2 = request.forms.get('xml')
    print(pprint(vars(request.POST)))
    print('-->' + xml1 +'<----')
    print(xml2)
    return 'trololo'

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

My output is

```
 {'dict': {'{"xml":"Fred","tags":"Flintstone"}': ['']}} 
 None  // don't know why this value appears here
 --><----  // xml1
 None // xml2
```

[Here](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#introducing-formsdict) is link to bottle docs, but I see no my mistake

Any ideas how to access parameters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON`. I believe you're using the Node.js library. Please consider use `querystring` to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/filter-tags', querystring.stringify({ 
   xml: 'Fred',
   tags: 'Flintstone'

}));
```

By doing this you will get `{'dict': {'xml': ['Fred'], 'tags': ['Flintstone']}}` which is very easy to get the datas. In this case just `request.POST.xml`

Comment: also its possible to request data as request.json['my-field'] without querystring usage